# How to find the row with the closest value to a given float in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Assuming that I have the following dataframe:

```
             col1       col2
0               0       0.53
1               1       0.52
```

How can I find the `col1` value and `col2` value for the row which has the closest `col2` value to e.g. `0.6`? 
For the given example the desired outcome would be:

```
closest_col1 = 0
closest_col2 = 0.53
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should do the trick:

```
closest_row = df.iloc[(df['col2'] - 0.6).abs().argsort()[:1]]
closest_col1 = closest_row[0][0]
closest_col2 = closest_row[0][1]
```

And now:

```
>> print(closest_col1)
>> print(closest_col2)
>> 0
>> 0.53
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `df.loc[(df.col2 - 0.6).abs().idxmin()]` gives you the row you want

Answer (score 2):

You can use idxmin:

```
closest_index = (data.col1 - data.col2).abs().idxmin()
print(data.loc[closest_index, :])
```