# Find Nearest Number To Target

Tags: python, sql

I have a database with 10 values simply listed as value1-10.

Every hour I have an export which triggers a python script, this script queries the database and sorts the data lowest to highest number. It also triggers with a number, at present it's a manual task to see what number is directly above and below it. I'm struggling to automate this.

A clearer example is something like this:

SQL Database > Python

Value1 - 10

Value2 - 20

Value3 - 30

Value4 - 40

Value5 - 50

Value6 - 60

Value7 - 70

Value8 - 80

Value9 - 90

Value10 - 100

10:00am: A trigger is launched and the script is fed number 65. So we have to check and say ok it's nearest lower value is 60 and nearest higher value is 70.

I'm trying to basically have Python do that task and spit out the value of the nearest numbers which I can then import back in another SQL Table.

Comment: Do you have a _question_? Please note SO isn't a code-writing service.

Comment: Just help with the logic really, happy to write the code but looking for a clue as to where to start. I've messed around with running a foreach loop on between each value and checking to see if the number is within the range, it kind of works but it's not very elegant. Wanted to check if anyone know a function that would fulfil the requirement I've checked to see if there is anything that would help in the statistics library as I use that heavily elsewhere.

Comment: I'm not completely sure reading this, but I think you're looking for the row with the closest value? If that's the case - I think this questions been answered over on this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60116838/how-to-find-the-row-with-the-closest-value-to-a-given-float-in-pandas

Comment: You have 2 possible approaches, one is to do what youre doing and use python in the middle to do the evaluation. The way I prefer, is to write a SQL statement that you can dynamically inject {65} and then have python write the SQL that specifically returns the 2 rows you want, using SQL logic only. I prefer this method because then python is only rendering the SQL and controlling the timing.

Comment: Thanks all this led me down some interesting paths after testing idxmin and pandas, I ended up finding numpy which is outputting the closest higher value. Shouldn't take me too long to get it doing the lower value as well.